# Return object using classnames and switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an object build out that has a bunch of methods inside, I want to be able to narrow down some methods and see if there are other ways to do thing, so I will go into more description below:

So I have the following method which returns me a bunch of class names:

```
function class_names() {
    return [
        'optanon-category-C0001',
        'optanon-category-C0002',
        'optanon-category-C0003',
        'optanon-category-C0004',
        'optanon-category-C0005'
    ];
}
```

Now I have another method which basically outputs me a string based on the classname passed inside the parameter:

```
function classname_output(class_name) {
    let output = '';
    switch (class_name) {
        case 'optanon-category-C0001':
            output = 'Strictly Necessary Cookies';
            break;
        case 'optanon-category-C0002':
            output = 'Performance Cookies';
            break;
        case 'optanon-category-C0003':
            output = 'Functional Cookies';
            break;
        case 'optanon-category-C0004':
            output = 'Targeting Cookies';
            break;
        case 'optanon-category-C0005':
            output = 'Social Media Cookies';
            break;
        default:
            output = 'No cookies match the specified class.';
            break;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is there a way that I can infuse the two methods into a single method with an object return and then target the object key?

Comment: What do you mean by *"infuse the two methods into a single method with an object return and then target the object key"*.

Comment: @Spectric, is there a way that I can do a method called classname and have a parameter, but then access a key of string, so like classname('optanon-category-C0001').string which would help me get rid of the switch statement.

Comment: Basically, store all the class names and their output inside a single method and then make a object return - So then I can access the method like `class_name('test').output` or `class_name('test').id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have object (dictionary) that maps class names (key) to string (value), and then have a function to return the value if the key exists in the dictionary, or a default "Doesn't exist" string if it doesn't.

```js
const dict = {
  'optanon-category-C0001': 'Strictly Necessary Cookies',
  'optanon-category-C0002': 'Performance Cookies',
  'optanon-category-C0003': 'Functional Cookies',
  'optanon-category-C0004': 'Targeting Cookies',
  'optanon-category-C0005': 'Social Media Cookies'
};

function check(dict, className) {
  return dict[className] ?? 'No cookies match the specified class.';
}

console.log(check(dict, 'optanon-category-C0003'));
console.log(check(dict, 'optanon-category-C0005'));
console.log(check(dict, 'optanon-category-C0000'));
```

Additional documentation

- [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Thanks @Andy, this is exactly what I was hinting at, but I wasn't sure how to properly execute it, will test now and follow up with a upvote.

Comment: Hey @Andy, I have another method that is dependent on the `class_names()` method that basically loops through `for (let i = 0; i < cookie_classes.length; i++) {` and checks all the classnames such as `if (target_node.hasClass(cookie_classes[i])) {` - Is there a way for me to loop through the dict object and reuse just the keys for another function?

Comment: You can get an array of keys with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys): `const classNames = Object.keys(dict)`. Is that what you meant?